# Can I avoid a children to exceed a certain dimension from an HOC component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've got an HOC :

```
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState<DimensionsType | null>(null);

 return (
   <View
      onLayout={(e) =>
        setDimensions({
          height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
          width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
        })
      }
      style={{
        maxWidth: wp('100%'),
        maxHeight: hp('100%'),
      }}
    >

      {dimensions && ( {children} )}
  </View >
)
```

This is a kind of container adding some padding around the children for styling purpose.

So the children cannot have a full screen dimension and must remains below a certain size that I want to set.

Is there a way to override the children height and width if it exceeds my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found how to override children props :

https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement